# is there any solution for : GLIBC_2.33 not found in arch linux?

Tags: linux, glibc, arch

i have installed Steam on Arch linux and then i tried to run 'pacman -Syu' and i got this error i tried downloading the package and put in the right path but nothing worked, and the steam client freeze on 'Connecting Steam Account' window.
this is it :

[devos@devarch ~]$ pacman -Syu

pacman: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by pacman)

pacman: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.12)

Comment: Boot from rescue cd, mount your filesystem, run `pacman --sysroot` and reinstall glibc and pacman. That is super strange tho, I suspect unrelated to your steam installation - most probably you only partially updated your system. On a rolling release, keep your packages up to date. Or, this looks like it: maybe steam installled newest glibc, but you did not install newest pacman. If you have docker running, you may try running pacman from docker to reinstall pacman on your host - but I would go with using rescue cd anyway, reinstall pacman and libgc, and update all packages.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i'll try that ;